# What does the errors=continue mount option mean?

Tags: linux, mount

On the output of the mount command on my system there are some lines like the following:

```
/dev/sda2 on /var/log type ext3 (rw,relatime,errors=continue,barrier=1,data=ordered)
```

And inside the parenthesis as you can see it says `errors=continue`. What does this mean?
Is there any error on the sda2 partition?
Shall i consider this or can I just ignore it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, that means that *if* there is an error, the system will ignore it.

There are three possible values for the `errors` option:

- `continue` (ignores the error)
- `remount-ro` (remount the filesystem read-only)
- `panic` (kernel panic).

Read `man 8 mount` for more informations.